# Grails config plugin grails-ckeditor through Spring Security

Tags: grails, spring-security, ckeditor, grails-plugin

I'm using Grails 3 with Spring Security Core Plugin.
I would like to use the grails-ckeditor plugin but I got some 403 error.

I don't get how to config the static rules. On my application.groovy I have this:

```
[pattern: '/ck',    access: 'permitAll'],
[pattern: '/ck.*',  access: 'permitAll'],
[pattern: '/ck/**', access: 'permitAll'],
```

But I always got 403 Error when I try to upload images.

Any idea?

Comment: My config has arrays for 'access' instead of String : access: ['permitAll']. Not sure this makes a difference though.

Comment: Thank you. But I did not work. Same result.

Answer (score 0):

what I did was override the OpenFileManagerConnectorController.

I created an **OpenFileManagerConnectorController** Controller and I pasted all the code from **OpenFileManagerConnectorController** file at GitHub.

Then I added the annotation security:

```
@Secured('ROLE_ADMIN')
class OpenFileManagerConnectorController
```

Not sure if it's the best solution but I worked as aspected.